# Vim delete parent parenthesis and reindent child

Tags: vim

I'm trying to go from here:

```
const f = function() {
    if (exists) { // delete this 
        const a = 'apple'
    }
}
```

to:

```
const f = function() {
    const a = 'apple'
}
```

What's the fastest way to delete and reindent everything in between?

Comment: can your `if` block have nested `{...}` and empty lines? Can your `if` have an else block too? if the answer is yes, what do you want to do with them?

Comment: There can be empty lines and nested `{...}`. If an else block complicates the problem, we can ignore it for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that cursor is inside the braces; any number of lines and nested operators; "else"-branch is not supported:

```
[{"_dd<]}']"_dd
```

Explanation:

`[{` go to previous unmatched brace

`"_dd` delete the "{"-line (now the cursor is in the first line of the block)

`<]}` decrease identation until the next unmatched "}"

`']` go to the last changed line (i.e. "}"-line)

`"_dd` and delete it

If the cursor is initially set on the "{"-line and you don't care for 1-9 registers, the command can be simplified to `dd<]}']dd`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your cursor is somewhere on the line containing `const a`

`?{^M%dd^Odd==` (where `^M` is you hitting the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key and `^O` is you hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>).

Broken down this is:
`?{^M` - search backwards/upwards for the opening brace
`%` - jump to the corresponding brace (closing brace)
`dd` - delete the current line
`^O` - jump to previous location (the opening brace)
`dd` - delete the line
`==` - indent current line

You don't need a special macro or function or anything to do this since vim gives you all the powerful text manipulation tools to do the task. If you find yourself doing this an awful lot then you *could* always map it to a key combination if you want.

The above only works for single lines inside curly braces, but the one below will work for multiple lines (again assuming you are on some line inside the curly braces)

`<i{0f{%dd^Odd` I'll leave you to figure out how this one works. Type the command slowly and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Great answers all around, and, as pointed out, you can always map these keys to a shortcut. If you'd like to try a slightly more generic solution, you could check my "deleft" plugin: https://github.com/AndrewRadev/deleft.vim